# How to open another .html file inside WKWebView when a link gets tapped?

Tags: html, webview, swiftui, href, wkwebview

I am using SwiftUI along with UIViewRepresentable to instantiate a WKWebView to display my html content:

### WebView

---

```
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

let request: URLRequest

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {

    return WKWebView()
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.load(self.request)
  }
}
```

### SwiftUI View

---

```
let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EULA for ALP app", withExtension: "html")

VStack{

   WebView(request: URLRequest(url: localFilePath!))

}.padding([.leading,.trailing],20)
```

### HTML

---

When I tap the span nothing happens as if its not registering the hit, I want to use another local HTML file like the one I am using inside the WebView so when the span gets tapped the WebView displays the corresponding file. I would also like to mention that HTML gets displayed correctly just without the href working.

```
<span href="file://practitionerPolicy.html">Tap Me!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume in this case, as this is your internal resources, relative path should work, like

```
<span href="practitionerPolicy.html">Tap Me!</span>
```

Comment: It is local path yes you are right. I changed my code to this but nothing is happening when tapping on the span. I am using the simulator so I wonder if it has something to do with that? 

One thing that is interesting is I cannot even get regular http links to work, I get no errors or warnings at all it just does not load anything when I tap/click on the span.